# Software / program language for newsfeed

Tags: api, automation, data-visualization, information-management, dashboard

So first off a little background information about the project i'm working on.
I'm doing research in how a local cinema can reach out to a specific target audience and share information with them for company branding purposes.

They are very interested in implementing a digital dashboard that will be screened in before a movie starts, so the visitors can read interesting stuff while waiting. Their idea is similar to this one, developed for the International Film Festival Rotterdam: https://vimeo.com/153362083. In this dashboard different types of information will be seen. Ranging from pure textual facts to social media feeds to images or animated media. The information probably won't be static so it also has to change/update like every 10 seconds.

Someone advised me to look into ReactJS since it's suitable for data-fetching with API's. However I would like to know if there's more worthy stuff out there to look into, alongside React. It's important that the effort to update the feed is as low as possible. If possible they want to have it update itself so after the launch no one has to put their hands on it anymore.

I don't have any information yet about how the feed will be fed to the movie projectors. I assume the software will run on a computer which will somehow be connected to the projectors, either wireless or wired.

The research i'm doing for now is still for advise purposes so any suggestion is welcome. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: React, Flutter, Python, Angular ... and many more can handle this. Use whichever you are comfortable with.